# Executing functions in order

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically, I'm making a small script to check the IP of some servers based on their hostname, then compare that IP to a list based on the IP block a router is issuing.

The problem I'm having is clearly with the code executing asynchronously, and it's likely been answered a thousand times, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to fix it. I've tried wrapping everything in promises but I end up breaking everything. Here is the latest attempt to break the steps I need out into individual functions.

```
const dns = require('dns');
const Table = require('cli-table');
const hosts = ['Server01', 'Server02', 'Server03'];
let list = [];

table = new Table({
    head: ['Host', 'Location']
    , colWidths: [20, 30]
});

function process() {
    hosts.forEach(host => {
        dns.lookup(host, function (err, result) {
            ipSplit = result.split(".");
            r = ipSplit[0] + '.' + ipSplit[1] + '.' + ipSplit[2];
            if (r == '10.23.13') {
                list.push([host, 'Lab A112']);
            }
            else {
                list.push([host, 'Unknown']);
            }
        });
    });
};

function build () {
    table.push(list);
};

function push () {
    console.log(table.toString());
};

process();
build();
push();
```

What piece of the puzzle am I missing here?

Comment: `Promise.all`. Use `Promise.all`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
const result = Promise.all(hosts.map(host => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    dns.lookup(host, function (err, result) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      const ipSplit = result.split(".");
      const r = ipSplit[0] + '.' + ipSplit[1] + '.' + ipSplit[2];
      if (r === '10.23.13') {
        resolve([host, 'Lab A112']);
      } else {
        resolve([host, 'Unknown']);
      }
    });
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order your function calls with **async/await** and you will get the order you need.

```
const dns = require('dns');
const Table = require('cli-table');
const hosts = ['Server01', 'Server02', 'Server03'];
let list = [];

table = new Table({
    head: ['Host', 'Location']
    , colWidths: [20, 30]
});

function process() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    hosts.forEach(host => {
        dns.lookup(host, function (err, result) {
            ipSplit = result.split(".");
            r = ipSplit[0] + '.' + ipSplit[1] + '.' + ipSplit[2];
            if (r == '10.23.13') {
                resolve(list.push([host, 'Lab A112']));
            }
            else {
                reject(list.push([host, 'Unknown']));
            }
        });
    });
  }) 
};

function build () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    resolve(table.push(list);)
  })

};

function push () {
    console.log(table.toString());
};
async function waitForFunctions() {
  try{
    const resOne = await process();
    const resTwo = await build()
  } catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
  return Promise.all([resOne, resTwo])
}
waitForFunctions()
.then((values)=>{
  console.log(values);
  console.log(push());
});
```

Comment: A little over complicated. the build function is synchronous by nature. You've crafted a answer to support a solution rather than a solution to support the question.

Comment: @RandyCasburn This is just how I interpret the problem and how I would have solved it. Yes, build is sync, but I need to make sure that it is not called **before** process function has finished, so I turn it into promise.

Comment: Fair enough. But that is already ensured with `process().then(()=>{build();push()}); This is much, much simpler and easier to comprehend.

Comment: @RandyCasburn the process function does not return anything from the original example, but yeas, there is definetally a shorter way to achieve the same thing, just **async/awit** for me is the simpler thing, but thats just me.

Comment: I meant you still need your promise returned from `process()` for sure. Didn't mean to be obscure. All good. Get your intent.